# Route 53 redirect AWS

Tags: routes, amazon-route53

I have a Website domain name **gearup.samsung.com**  in another AWS account and there is a hosted zone in route 53 created for it and there are servers in that aws account and Recently I have created a new servers are domain name named **gearup.com** and created a new hosted zone in route 53 for it in another AWS account, Now I want all my users to redirect who type **gearup.samsung.com** in their browser to **gearup.com** , Is that possible...? If possible, How can i do it...?

please help

Thanks,
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect a domain using Route 53. As per the [instructions here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/), you need to create an S3 bucket and Route 53 rules in order to redirect a domain.

> 1. In the Amazon S3 console, create an S3 bucket with the exact name as example.com.
>
> Note: S3 bucket names must be globally unique. If the bucket name you need is already in use, this solution cannot be used.
>
> 2. Select the bucket you just created, and then choose Properties. Expand the Static Website Hosting drop-down menu, and then choose Redirect all requests to another host name.
> 3. In the Redirect all requests to another host name field, enter example.net and then choose Save.
> 4. In the Route 53 console, select the hosted zone named example.com.
> 5. Create a resource record for example.com with the following values:
>
>    - Record Type: Choose A IPv4 address.
>    - Alias: Choose Yes.
>    - Alias Target: Select the blank value field, expand the drop-down menu, and then choose your S3 bucket under the heading S3 Website Endpoints.
>    - Routing Policy: Choose Simple.
>    - Evaluate Health Target: Choose No and then choose Create.
>        Note: The drop-down menu might take a few moments to populate your bucket name.

Answer (score 0):

If your website is based on php then. You don't need to do much changes.
Just make sure redirection site is working perfectly.

After that under your apache configuration just add
Redirect Permanently [domain]